# Calling a cpp function inside RDCOMClient package

Tags: r, rdcomclient

New to R programming so bear with me.

I am trying to call a function defined in a cpp file inside the *RDCOMClient* package called *R_convertDCOMObjectToR*. I did not write that package - it's available here: https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient

I try to call it like this:

```
.Call("R_convertDCOMObjectToR", varQuestionNames, PACKAGE = "RDCOMClient")
```

But I get the following error:

> Error in .Call("R_convertDCOMObjectToR", varQuestionNames, PACKAGE =
>   "RDCOMClient") :    "R_convertDCOMObjectToR" not available for .Call()
>   for package "RDCOMClient"

Is there anyway to make that function visible? should I ask the author to change his library?

Thanks for any pointer!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rcpp so I will remove the `[rcpp]` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You simply cannot call any given C function from any given package *unless that package exports it*.

See [Writing R Extensions, Section 5.4.3](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Linking-to-native-routines-in-other-packages), several example usages in various packages (such as eg my [RApiSerialize](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rapiserialize.html) and [RApiDatetime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rapidatetime.html)), and other questions here on the site.

Comment: Thanks Dirk - I am actually reading your "Seamless R and C++ integration" and I am clearly only at the beginning. And apologies if I have wasted your time...